# applicationContext.xml and other configuration files - where should they go?

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven-2, jpa

I'm developing a new Spring+JPA2/Hibernate+Wicket project and am wondering where some of the configuration files should go?

**applicationContext.xml**
I've seen this both in src/main/resources/META-INF and just src/main/resources/

**persistence.xml**
Most of the time, I've seen it in src/main/resources/META-INF. In my case, it contains the following:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="ApplicationEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**web.xml**
I guess src/main/webapp/WEB-INF is the correct place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `persistence.xml` must be in `src/main/resources/META-INF`
- `applicationContext.xml` can be anywhere, as long as you configure it with `contextConfigLocation`. By default spring looks for it in `WEB-INF`, so it has to be in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. But I  think it better be in `src/main/resources`.

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

Note that for unit tests you can override these files by placing the test-alternatives in `src/test/**`

Generally speaking, all resources should be in `src/main/resources`. (reraly in `META-INF`)